# sybase - Is there any performance difference between count(*) and count(1)

Tags: performance, count, sybase

#### Query 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM STUDENTS
```

#### Query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENTS
```

Both the queries return the same result, but is there any performance difference between these two ?

What I had heard is the first query would be faster than the second one, but can any one give specific details about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count(*) vs Count(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `count(*)` or `count(1)`, one is not faster than the other. As stated, is just a *urban* legend :)

---

One final note, `count(*)` and `count(columnName)` **may be different!**
The first one counts all rows, the second one counts the number of rows where the specified column is not NULL.

Comment: Note that COUNT(Column) may require a table scan (slow) where COUNT(*) may not (basic table metadata).

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference whatsoever between the two statements.

The rumour that `count(1)` is faster is an urban legend that was never true.

Comment: And this is a DBMS-agnostic answer; it doesn't matter which DBMS you use!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes, absolutely.